# Put a UIImageView in the background

Tags: iphone, xcode

Here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  int rand2 = arc4random() % 5;
  switch (rand2) {
  case 0: 
    imgView =   [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinkfont.png"]];          
    break;
  case 1:
imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenfont.png"]];
        break;
  case 2:
    imgView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whitefont.png"]];
    break;
  case 3:
    imgView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowfont.png"]];
    break;
  case 4:
    imgView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"purplefont.png"]];
    break;
   }


   [[[self view] layer] addSublayer:[imgView layer]];
   [imgView release];

}
```

I want to put imgView at the background, but it doesn't work, I tried to do it with interface Builder with "send to back" but no result. How can I solve this please?

Sorry for my english I'm french :)

Comment: If I can give you any unrelated device; it would be a great time saver if you put all those file names in an array, and choose an index of that array at random, put that into a UIImageView. That will save you LOTS of code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have xib file then drag a image view in your xib file and then from menu tab select layoutand choose sent to back or backward.
or you have to create dynamically  then write

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
[self.view addSubview:imgView];

[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgView];
```

Check after this code, you are not adding other views in viewWillAppear, if you add other views, send subview to back again.

Comment: but here it's a layer and not a view

Answer (score 0):

write this line of code at the end of your viewwillappear method.

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgView];
```

Answer (score 0):

to set image as your view background use this

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinkfont.png"]
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img]];
```